# Laravel Image uploading on hosting server not working although working on local server

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

My project was working well in Local Server(XAMPP). But after uploading my project on hosting server(000WebHost), I'm not being able to upload any Image on server.

After renaming `public` directory to `public_html`, I added this code into `register()` method of `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```
$this -> app -> bind('path.public', function(){
    return base_path('public_html');
});
```

I also tried using `base_path()` instead of `public_path()` in my code, it didn't work also.

My code:

```
if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
    $avatar=$request->file('avatar');
    $filename=Auth::user()->id.'_'.time().'.'.$avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location=public_path('images/avatar/'.$filename);
    Image::make($avatar)->resize(400, 400)->save($location);

    $prf->avatar=$filename;
}
```

Comment: Can you read the `error.log` ? What eroor do you have?

Comment: Have you made edits to config/filesystems?

Comment: Yes. I edited Config/app.php file. I enabled app_debug_mode & added base64 key.

Comment: no config/filesystems.php